# .NET Reflector error in generating code

Tags: decompiling, .net-reflector

I used Reflector 6.8 to disassemble a binary. It shows the Class tree view. Even the declaration of methods of the classes , but "Expand Methods" errors out with some error like "Block statement count of 0 during conditional expression translation"

Then I tried to use Telerik's JustDecompile (in Beta), it worked fine for 1 of the 10-15 assemblies i have. But for another assembly it simply shoots up in memory to 1.5 GB and hangs.

Is there any other stable decompiler I can use to generate C# code ?

Answer (score 3):

The only other one that I know of is [IL Spy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx).

You should report errors in Reflector to the guys at Red Gate.

Comment: thanks. i reported. and was trying ILSpy.. Seems to work good. 1 thing i noticed is that it is geenrating some weired nested while loop at start of every method and property. Though that loop has break and it is like NOP.  while(true) { while(!true) {....} break; }  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The no-op loops were probably added by some obfuscator.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the available information, I believe you may be using an obfuscated assembly.

The current Telerik JustDecompile beta (2011.1.728.1) does not offer support for decompiling obfuscated assemblies. It is very efficient at decompiling non-obfuscated assemblies, though, and its memory footprint is getting smaller with every update. The memory usage you observed is unusual. If you can share more detail over email about the assembly you’re using, we’ll try to reproduce and fix this specific case (chris.eargle [at] telerik.com).

Meanwhile, if you’d like to see more support in future JustDecompile updates for obfuscated assemblies, please share your feedback on the JustDecompile UserVoice so others can vote for the idea: http://justdecompile.uservoice.com.